# @Model annotation and MVC

Tags: java, terminology, java-ee-6, cdi

The [Weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html_single/) states that the `javax.enterprise.inject.Model` annotation is designed for Controllers (logical because it marks bean as `@RequestScoped` and `@Named`).

But why is it named as Model instead of Controller?

Comment: Should I use Model or write my own stereotype annotation named as Controller for controller classes of my JSF application?

Comment: Your question raises a valid point which I cannot answer. However, don't worry too much about writing your own annotation - if you feel like using `@Controller` over `@Model`, just do it. CDI's typesafe qualification mechanism is designed to give you maximum flexibility in expressing your logic.

Answer (score 4):

Because the specification does not assume you use a pattern that involves having controllers in the first place.

There's other patterns and naming conventions out there. For example seam uses a "Action" instead of "Controller" (all though those concepts do not map entirely)